# How to display the title of the group in sharepoint list view?

Tags: list-view, grouping, title-column

I have this dispay. Notice the number right after the "Periode" group heading.

[image]

I want that. 
Notice that the group heading is now have **2018-06** near the number of elements inside the groupe.

[image]

Notice that all document inside the group starts with the same set of characters i.e. *2018-06*.
I would like to have a solution that does not implty any JS or C# code.
Thank you all.

Comment: You can create a calculated column which would include the starting part of the item title "2018-06". And then by applying "GroupBy" to that particular calculated column. You can achieve it.

Comment: Follow this link to create the calculated column using Name column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545071/sharepoint-2010-calculated-column-based-on-name-field

Comment: Thank you Niranjan you can submit you comment as an anwser. I'll be glad to mark it as a valide answer.

Comment: Ok fine sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a calculated column which would include the starting part of the item title "2018-06". And then by applying "GroupBy" to that particular calculated column. We can achieve it.

Follow below link to create the calculated column using Name column,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545071/sharepoint-2010-calculated-column-based-on-name-field